# How to print String ArrayList?

Tags: java

I have a loop in which i put `splited` parts of a string using object. Need to put them in a `ArrayList` and print the list, hod do i do that?

I tried to use for loop too, to print it.

```
for(int i = 0; i < parts.length; i += 4) {
            p.name = parts[i];
            p.lastName = parts[i + 1];
            p.dateBirth = LocalDate.parse(parts[i + 2], df1);
            p.placeBirth = parts [i + 3];
        }

        ArrayList lista = new ArrayList();
            lista.add(parts);
```

It should print things from `ArrayList` which i should add.

Comment: Need to put _what_ in an `ArrayList`? the `p` object(s)? This is very unclear, please clarify.

Comment: This parts are splited strings, that i need to separate using object p and call it in main. After i call an object in the loop, i need to put it in the ArrayList, and ,most importantlly,call the ArrayList.

Answer (score 1):

If your `parts` is a `String[]` array then you can convert it to a list quickly with

```
List<String> lista = Arrays.asList(parts);
```

There are many options to print all elements. You can iterate with a for-each loop:

```
for(String part: lista) {
   System.out.println(part);
}
```

Or you can use a more compact approach, lambda expressions:

```
lista.forEach(part -> System.out.println(part));
```